# Android: SQLite Database deleting all rows when opening pre-existing database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to open an SQLite database to update it with new rows. The trouble is, opening the database seems to delete all rows in it. Here is my code:

```
    String sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myApp";
    String databasePath = sdPath + "/myApp.db";
    File file = new File( databasePath );

    if( file.exists() )
    {
        Log.w( getClass().getSimpleName() , "myApp Database size: " + file.length() );
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase( file, null );
        Log.w( getClass().getSimpleName() , "myApp Database size: " + file.length() );
        Log.w( getClass().getSimpleName() , "myApp Database opened" );
    }
    else
    {
        File directory = new File( sdPath );
        directory.mkdir();
        Log.w( getClass().getSimpleName() , "Creating myApp Database" );
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase( file, null );
        Log.w( getClass().getSimpleName() , "myApp Database opened" );
        database.execSQL( DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_OBJECT );
        database.execSQL( DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_ZONE );
        database.execSQL( DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_OBJECT_ZONE );
        database.execSQL( DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_POINT );
        database.execSQL( DATABASE_CREATE_INDEX_POINT );
        database.execSQL( DATABASE_CREATE_INDEX_ZONE );
    }
```

On my two output statements, the first tells me the size of the file before opening it, and then after opening, the file size always returns to approximately 13KB. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I should probably mention that I'm writing this nor Android API level 7.

Comment: Are you sure it's your file.exists block that is being executed and not the else block?

Comment: Based on the log messages that I output in both blocks, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this...

```
    String sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myApp";
    String databasePath = sdPath + "/myApp.db";
    File file = new File( databasePath );
```

With this...

```
private File myAppDir = null;
private File databaseFile = null;

...

// Automatically creates /mnt/sdcard/.../myApp folder if it doesn't already exist
if (myAppDir == null)
    myAppDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath());

if (databaseFile == null)
    databaseFile = new File(myAppDir, "/myApp.db");
```

Then use this with your if/else code...

```
if (databaseFile.exists())
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

**BUT remove these two lines from the 'else' block**...

```
File directory = new File( sdPath );
directory.mkdir();
```

Comment: I just tried this, though I didn't know how it would really be any different to what I was already doing. Unfortunately, I still get the same problem. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, it seems I did something stupid with my transactions when I first create the database. They started nesting, but didn't all get closed. That'll teach me to not use my loops properly.